# How to say "increase the food price" in Chinese?

Tags: translation, phrase

学校餐厅的开支增加了，这样一来，餐厅就会 increase the food price.

How do I say "increase the food price" in Chinese?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify your context?  Are you saying (food) expeditures (i. e., operating costs) have increased or the price of meals (i. e. consumer costs)  in the cafteria have increased?

Comment: The most simple one may be: 学校餐厅的开支增加了，这样一来，餐厅就会「涨价」。Probably it's not grammartically right but people will know the meaning :).

Answer (score 1):

Word by word, the translation is:

increase(提高/增加 ti gao / zeng jia);

the food(食物shi wu);

的(pinyin: de, meaning the food'**S** price, or price **OF** the food.  The character is added to express that the price is the food's);

price (价格jia ge)

So the whole sentence would be, 提高食物的价格

Although in short, you can simply say 涨价(zhang jia) meaning to increase price as @user-487 answered above.

Comment: “食品” is better than “食物” in this context. “食品“ is more formal and is more often used for human food, while “食物” is usually used for animals.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Chinese, We always say 学校餐厅的开支增加了，这样一来，餐厅就会**涨价**.
Because it's weird to call particular thing like "食物/food". And a restaurant always provide food, It's not necessary to say "增长食物的价格"(wordy)...

Answer (score 0):

Basically,it's more appropriate to say "学校餐厅的开支增加了，这样一来，菜价就会上涨了"

Answer (score 0):

The original sentences contains redundancy.

Though I can "fill in the blank" as

学校餐厅的开支增加了，这样一来，餐厅`的食物就会涨价`。

I will like this more
开支增加了，这样一来，学校餐厅`的食物就会涨价`。

better  : 
开支增加了，学校餐厅`就会涨价， 把成本转移到学生身上`。

Answer (score 0):

I will translate it as “提高饭菜的价格”. “食品” is more general than “饭菜”, but sounds too general. If this sentence is describing cafeterias in Chinese universities, “饭菜” will suffice because it is unlikely they will provide anything other than 饭 and 菜 (e.g. soft drink and ice cream, which are usually sold elsewhere).